Saving a QQrplot object as an image
I am plotting qqrplot objects (from the countregpackage) as a form of validation of zero-inflated and hurdle regression models.
zinb_qq <- qqrplot(zinb_model, main = "Quantile-Quantile residuals plot (ZINB)"), 
hnb_qq <- qqrplot(hnb_model, main = "Quantile-Quantile residuals plot (HNB)")

It has come to my attention that the qqrplot object doesn't just output a graph, they also output an "invisible list of the theoretical and empirical quantiles. So whenever I try to save the plot:

With the png() and dev.off()functions: I get a white image, with no plot;
With the recordPlot()function: I also get a white image, with no plot;
With the ggsavefunction: I get the error Error in UseMethod("grid.draw") :  no applicable method for 'grid.draw' applied to an object of class "list"
When I output the saved plots, I only get the list of numbers.

Has anyone had this problem? Do you see any alternative to solve this?
Thanks.

The qqrplot function works through ggplot, so you can save the plots using the  ggsave like so:
qqrplot(zinb_model, main = "Quantile-Quantile residuals plot (ZINB)")

ggsave('img_name_zinb.png')

qqrplot(hnb_model, main = "Quantile-Quantile residuals plot (HNB)")

ggsave('img_name_hnb.png')

As far as I can tell, the error stems from trying to save the zinb_qq object using ggsave, as the qqrplot function returns a list not a ggplot object. So, you would need to save each plot before creating a new one.
